# Multiindex assigning while avoiding SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas, warnings

This code works, but generates SettingWithCopyWarning.  Since the warning can be useful, I'd rather not turn it off globally.  In other cases I've found ways to achieve the same result, without triggering the warning, but I can't think of an alternative here:

```
# df does not yet have a ColZ
# df is indexed by Date and Name (which is not use here)
df["ColZ"] = 0.0
Z = df.xs(myDate, level="Date", drop_level=False)["ColZ"]
Z[:36] = 99.0
df.loc[(myDate,), ("ColZ",)] = Z
```

I can't take the cross section (`xs`) and then assign to a new column, because the cross section will give me a copy.  And I can't take a cross section for just the cells I want to set to 99, because I need to slice by index AND by row, so I need a blend of iloc and loc.  One possibility would be to reset the index to drop the Name level and then put it back again afterward, but that seems yucky.

Any suggestions, or do I just live with the warning?

Comment: Could you try and see if just making a copy of the dataframe will solve the problem? It's not a good solution, but it gives an indication on what the problem could be. Just do `df = df.copy()` on the line before the warning is triggered.

Comment: @firelynx this still seems to raise the warning

Comment: @firelynx that inspired me to try the opposite though: putting `.copy()` after `["ColZ"]` stops the warning, weird....

Comment: See the thing is that you are setting data on a copy of a slice of a dataframe... litterally this is your problem. the `.copy()` stops the instance from being a slice, and makes it a real instance. So the problem is that you are using `["ColZ"]` and then `Z[:36]`. You should just use `.loc()`, as the warning suggests, it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can disable the warning by following code:

```
with pd.option_context('mode.chained_assignment',None):
    you code here
```